# Удаление элементов контейнера

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Ребят, такое дело.
Вроде бы задание элементарное, но я все не могу дать ему ума.

Само задание:

```
template<typename FwdIt, typename Pred>
FwdIt remove_if(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Pred pr);
```

Нужно написать алгоритм, который удаляет из диапазона [first , last) все элементы, для которых значение предиката pr равно true. Удаленные элементы сдвигаются в конец контейнера. Возвращает итератор на первый удаленный элемент.

Ведь итератор это указатель на элемент контейнера, и вот как через него удалять элементы?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: Трюк здесь в том, что `std::remove_if` ничего не удаляет, а просто переставляет элементы. Если не хотите ломать голову самостоятельно, то ключевые слова — `remove_if` и `cppreference`.

Answer (score 4):

Эх, так вопрос и не получил канонического ответа.

Вы должны на самом деле воспользоваться [идиомой erase/remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Код того, как надо делать, можно найти [на cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
std::string str = "Text\n with\tsome \t  whitespaces\n\n";
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), 
                         str.end(),
                         [](char x){return std::isspace(x);}),
          str.end());
```

`std::remove_if` перемещает ненужные элементы в конец, и возвращает итератор на *первый* из них. Так что удалять надо от этого итератора и до конца. Именно это и делает `remove`.

Для чего всё так сложно? Дело в том, что `remove_if` не знает ни о контейнере, ни о том, как удалить элемент по итератору. Поэтому он может лишь перемещать элементы.

Некоторые контейнеры (например, `set`/`map`), [не могут быть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792615/276994) использованы таким образом, поскольку в них менять элемент по итератору запрещено, и `remove` не скомпилируется. Для них можно использовать [такую конструкцию](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase):

```
std::set<int> s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); /**/)
{
    if (<condition>)
        it = s.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Для других типов (например, `list`) идиома erase/remove слишком неэффективна, и для них стоит пользоваться [их собственной имплементацией `remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove).

Comment: Сейчас столкнулся с этим явлением, и как выяснилось std::remove_if(...); может вернуть end() - невалидный итератор. что при передаче в <CONTAINER>::erase приведет к неопределенному поведению. К примеру у меня на MSVC2015 x64 приводило к access_violation. Однако на x86 или arm-gcc 4.8 или gcc7 x86|64 ошибки не возникало. В общем отследить удалось только из-за большого количества платформ. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: @JK_Action: а можно воспроизводящий пример? [Документация](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) говорит, что `erase(end, end)` должен нормально работать.

Comment: я тут немного ошибся я имел ввиду конструкцию erase(it)  и конкретно в моеv случае был std::deque

Comment: http://cpp.sh/5yvl7

Comment: @JK_Action: А, это да, в идиоме erase/remove нужно пользоваться erase с двумя аргументами, иначе проблем не избежать (в случае, когда `remove_if` находит не 1 результат, а больше или меньше).

Answer (score 2):

1. читаем справку по С++ [RU](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm),
       [EN](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)
2. постигаем разницу между
       Sequence и Associative 
       containers [тык](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) и незабываем подумать...
3. собственно как удалить что то из
       контейнера
       [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/), [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/), [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)