# Удалить все вхождения определённого символа в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Чтобы удалить все вхождения определённого символа в строке используется код:

```
string.erase(std::remove(string.begin(), string.end(), '\r'), string.end());
```

В с++ до сих пор нет человеческих функций типа `remove('\r')` ?

P.S. с++ язык для роботов и мечтать о человеческом синтаксисе бессмысленно.
 Поэтому строка `string.erase(std::remove(string.begin(), string.end(), '\r'), string.end());` будет обернута в функцию типа `remove_from(std::string& string, char symbol);`
А в коде будет `remove_from(my_string, '\r');`

Comment: @freim [std::remove](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: @freim, "все" = все вхождения какого-либо символа) std::remove - это вы путаете с чем-то другим)

Comment: В C++ используется  [erase-remove идиома](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426177/276430) так же написано как, что и почему

Comment: @BeaverFeller скорее там написано какая же это убогая идиома: и сложно, и длинно, и для некоторых контейнеров не подходит, и для некоторых неэффективна.

Comment: Кроме чистого С++ в проекте ничего нет?

Comment: @älёxölüt, нет (еще один символ нужен, чтобы я мог написать ответ нет, ведь нет это слишком коротко для этого сайта)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартная библиотека никогда не славилась разнообразием всевозможных функций из коробки, и часто приходится не то чтобы изобретать велосипед, но реализовывать некоторые несложные обёртки, дабы достичь необходимого удобства.

Алгоритмы C++ базируются на работе с итераторами, а это значит, что о контейнере, который хранит итерируемые элементы, они ничего не знают. Поэтому и появляются такие вложенные вызовы как `erase`, `remove`.

Как вариант можно использовать [`boost::erase_all`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/erase_all.html). При условии, если проект уже использует *boost* это будет наиболее простым и наглядным решением, как мне кажется. А учитывая, что из буста регулярно что-то переезжает в новый стандарт, может быть когда-нибудь эту функцию увидим и внутри `std::`.

Comment: к сожалению буст не вариант. Придется дальше сидет на костылях)